# How to resize image in css without cropping it?

Tags: html, css

I hav a div tag.In it's css properties i've put the image and the tried to resize it using height and width properties.But instead of shrinking it is getting cropped! How am i supposed to scale it using height and width?

Comment: WHAT css properties? There's MANY css properties

Comment: Please share relevant code sample with your question

Comment: use background-size: 100% 100%

Comment: You could set the `min-width` & `min-height` to `100%`

Comment: @Jack no. OP is talking about `background-image` and all OP has to do is learn about `background-size`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Okay, I realize that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-image:url(img.jpg)
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

If image is used as a background.  Not sure exactly how your code is set up.

Comment: Yup that worked! Thanks for solving the problem! :)